# Conditional sum of dataframe columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, if-statement, conditional-statements

Keen to know if it's possible to reproduce the following logic in Python, in one line, without creating a function.

```
z = IF (y-x) = 0 THEN a ELSE (y-x)
```

Using this df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [10, 22, 31, 43, 57, 99, 65, 74, 88],
              'y':[10, 50, 31, 66, 57, 199, 75, 80, 100]})
```

which looks like:

```
    x    y
0  10   10
1  22   50
2  31   31
3  43   66
4  57   57
5  99  199
6  65   75
7  74   80
8  88  100
```

To produce the following output:

```
 x  y   z
10  10  10
22  50  28
31  31  31
43  66  23
57  57  57
99  199 100
65  75  10
74  80  6
88  100 12
```

I have attempted the following but this returns a syntax error.

```
z = if(y - x) == 0: a else: (y - x)
```

I appreciate there are similar questions but I haven't found anything that is applicable to my use case or has a sufficient explanation such that I can repurpose the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np
df['z'] = np.where(df['x']==df['y'], df['x'], df['y'] - df['x'])
```

Here, the condition `df['x']==df['y']` creates a boolean Series of length `len(df)` ordered in the same order as `df`, i.e. with the same index. Then wherever True, you take the value from `df['x']` in the corresponding index and wherever False, you take the value from `df['y'] - df['x']` in the corresponding index. As it's clear from the previous sentence, all three Series must have the same length (or must be broadcastable).

The output we get (that we assign to `df['z']`) is and array of length `len(df)` with elements from `df['x']` where our condition is True, and elements from `df['y'] - df['x']` otherwise.

From the docs:

> If all the arrays are 1-D, where is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> [xv if c else yv
>  for c, xv, yv in zip(condition, x, y)]
> ```

and since we have 1-D arrays here, we could also use

```
df['z'] = [x if c else y_minus_x 
           for c, x, y_minus_x in zip(df['x']==df['y'], df['x'], df['y'] - df['x'])]
```

for the same results.

Output:

```
    x    y    z
0  10   10   10
1  22   50   28
2  31   31   31
3  43   66   23
4  57   57   57
5  99  199  100
6  65   75   10
7  74   80    6
8  88  100   12
```